# SVG Color transition does not work on hover

Tags: css, svg, colors

I'm trying to make a simple SVG button using CSS. I have managed to change the color on hover but color transition does not seem to work for me. I'd like to have at least 1s transition time. Here is the code I'm using:

SVG:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 162 113"><title>Telephone</title><g id="Page-1"><g id="Artboard-2"><g id="Group-13"><g id="Group-4"><g id="Group-9"><rect id="Rectangle" x="1" y="1" width="160" height="111" rx="8" ry="8" fill="none" stroke="#2b7db5" stroke-width="2"/></g></g><g id="icons8-phone_office" data-name="icons8-phone office"><rect id="Rectangle-path" x="55.24" y="36.31" width="55.86" height="49.66" rx="3" ry="3" fill="#c2cde7"/><path id="Shape" d="M59.38,72.52H107a4.14,4.14,0,0,1,4.14,4.14v6.21A3.1,3.1,0,0,1,108,86H58.34a3.1,3.1,0,0,1-3.1-3.1V76.66A4.14,4.14,0,0,1,59.38,72.52Z" fill="#acb7d0"/><path id="Shape-2" data-name="Shape" d="M68.69,36.31H108a3.1,3.1,0,0,1,3.1,3.1V54.93H65.59V39.41A3.1,3.1,0,0,1,68.69,36.31Z" fill="#bbdef9"/><polygon id="Shape-3" data-name="Shape" points="78.18 54.93 92.31 36.31 108.86 36.31 94.73 54.93 78.18 54.93" fill="#def0ff"/><polygon id="Shape-4" data-name="Shape" points="69.94 54.93 84.68 36.31 88.17 36.31 73.43 54.93 69.94 54.93" fill="#def0ff"/><polygon id="Shape-5" data-name="Shape" points="66.96 52.86 80.07 36.31 81.1 36.31 68 52.86 66.96 52.86" fill="#def0ff"/><path id="Shape-6" data-name="Shape" d="M66.62,32.17H53.17V28H49V76.66a3.1,3.1,0,0,0,3.1,3.1H66.62a3.1,3.1,0,0,0,3.1-3.1V35.28A3.1,3.1,0,0,0,66.62,32.17Z" fill="#c2cde7"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-2" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="49.03" y="72.52" width="20.69" height="7.24" rx="3" ry="3" fill="#acb7d0"/><path id="Shape-7" data-name="Shape" d="M53.17,32.17h14a2.59,2.59,0,0,1,2.59,2.59h0a2.59,2.59,0,0,1-2.59,2.59h-14Z" fill="#ced9ed"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-3" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="75.93" y="61.14" width="6.21" height="6.21" fill="#ed7899"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-4" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="86.28" y="61.14" width="6.21" height="6.21" fill="#85cbf8"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-5" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="96.62" y="61.14" width="6.21" height="6.21" fill="#85cbf8"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-6" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="75.93" y="71.48" width="6.21" height="6.21" fill="#85cbf8"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-7" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="86.28" y="71.48" width="6.21" height="6.21" fill="#85cbf8"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-8" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="96.62" y="71.48" width="6.21" height="6.21" fill="#72caaf"/><path id="Shape-8" data-name="Shape" d="M81.1,60.1H77a2.07,2.07,0,0,0-2.07,2.07v4.14A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,77,68.38H81.1a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07-2.07V62.17A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,81.1,60.1Zm0,6.21H77V62.17H81.1Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-9" data-name="Shape" d="M91.45,60.1H87.31a2.07,2.07,0,0,0-2.07,2.07v4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07,2.07h4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07-2.07V62.17A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,91.45,60.1Zm0,6.21H87.31V62.17h4.14Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-10" data-name="Shape" d="M91.45,70.45H87.31a2.07,2.07,0,0,0-2.07,2.07v4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07,2.07h4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07-2.07V72.52A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,91.45,70.45Zm0,6.21H87.31V72.52h4.14Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-11" data-name="Shape" d="M101.79,70.45H97.66a2.07,2.07,0,0,0-2.07,2.07v4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07,2.07h4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07-2.07V72.52A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,101.79,70.45Zm0,6.21H97.66V72.52h4.14Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-12" data-name="Shape" d="M101.79,60.1H97.66a2.07,2.07,0,0,0-2.07,2.07v4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07,2.07h4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07-2.07V62.17A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,101.79,60.1Zm0,6.21H97.66V62.17h4.14Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-13" data-name="Shape" d="M81.1,70.45H77a2.07,2.07,0,0,0-2.07,2.07v4.14A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,77,78.72H81.1a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07-2.07V72.52A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,81.1,70.45Zm0,6.21H77V72.52H81.1Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-14" data-name="Shape" d="M78,46.73h1v1H78a1,1,0,1,0,0,2.07h2.07a1,1,0,0,0,1-1v-3.1a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H79V43.55h1a1,1,0,0,0,0-2.07H78a1,1,0,0,0-1,1v3.1a1,1,0,0,0,1,1.11Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-15" data-name="Shape" d="M84.21,46.73h1v1h-1a1,1,0,1,0,0,2.07h2.07a1,1,0,0,0,1-1v-3.1a1,1,0,0,0-1-1h-1V43.55h1a1,1,0,0,0,0-2.07H84.21a1,1,0,0,0-1,1v3.1a1,1,0,0,0,1,1.11Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-16" data-name="Shape" d="M90.41,46.73h1v1h-1a1,1,0,0,0,0,2.07h2.07a1,1,0,0,0,1-1v-3.1a1,1,0,0,0-1-1h-1V43.55h1a1,1,0,1,0,0-2.07H90.41a1,1,0,0,0-1,1v3.1a1,1,0,0,0,1,1.11Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-17" data-name="Shape" d="M100.76,46.73h1v1h-1a1,1,0,1,0,0,2.07h2.07a1,1,0,0,0,1-1v-3.1a1,1,0,0,0-1-1h-1V43.55h1a1,1,0,0,0,0-2.07h-2.07a1,1,0,0,0-1,1v3.1a1,1,0,0,0,1,1.11Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-18" data-name="Shape" d="M109,35.28H70.66a5.17,5.17,0,0,0-5.07-4.14H54.21v-1a3.1,3.1,0,0,0-6.21,0V75.62a5.17,5.17,0,0,0,5.17,5.17h1v3.1a3.1,3.1,0,0,0,3.1,3.1H109a3.1,3.1,0,0,0,3.1-3.1V38.38A3.1,3.1,0,0,0,109,35.28ZM51.1,29.07a1,1,0,0,1,1,1v8.28a1,1,0,0,0,2.07,0V33.21H65.59a3.1,3.1,0,0,1,3.1,3.1V72.52H50.07V30.1A1,1,0,0,1,51.1,29.07Zm-1,46.55v-1H68.69v1a3.1,3.1,0,0,1-3.1,3.1H53.17A3.1,3.1,0,0,1,50.07,75.62Zm59,9.31H57.31a1,1,0,0,1-1-1v-3.1h9.31a5.17,5.17,0,0,0,5.17-5.17V37.34H109a1,1,0,0,1,1,1V53.9H82.14a1,1,0,1,0,0,2.07h27.93V83.9A1,1,0,0,1,109,84.93Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-19" data-name="Shape" d="M95.59,46.66h2.07a1,1,0,0,0,0-2.07H95.59a1,1,0,1,0,0,2.07Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-20" data-name="Shape" d="M54.21,57a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V53.9a1,1,0,1,0-2.07,0V56A1,1,0,0,0,54.21,57Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-21" data-name="Shape" d="M59.38,57a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V53.9a1,1,0,0,0-2.07,0V56A1,1,0,0,0,59.38,57Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-22" data-name="Shape" d="M64.55,57a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V53.9a1,1,0,1,0-2.07,0V56A1,1,0,0,0,64.55,57Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-23" data-name="Shape" d="M79,54.93a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H73.86a1,1,0,0,0,0,2.07H78A1,1,0,0,0,79,54.93Z" fill="#2b7db5"/></g></g></g></g></svg>
```

CSS

```
svg:hover #Rectangle{ fill: #DAF0FF; }
#Rectangle{ transition: 1s; }
```

https://codepen.io/Vitamin-b/pen/OjgwOd

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give `#Rectangle` a starting value in order for the transition to work. As it needs a value to transition to/from. For example:

```
#Rectangle{
  fill: white;
  transition: 1s; 
}
```

```css
#Rectangle{
  fill: white; /*Add starting fill*/
  transition: 1s; }
svg:hover #Rectangle{ 
  fill: #DAF0FF; 
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 162 113"><title>Telephone</title><g id="Page-1"><g id="Artboard-2"><g id="Group-13"><g id="Group-4"><g id="Group-9"><rect id="Rectangle" x="1" y="1" width="160" height="111" rx="8" ry="8" fill="none" stroke="#2b7db5" stroke-width="2"/></g></g><g id="icons8-phone_office" data-name="icons8-phone office"><rect id="Rectangle-path" x="55.24" y="36.31" width="55.86" height="49.66" rx="3" ry="3" fill="#c2cde7"/><path id="Shape" d="M59.38,72.52H107a4.14,4.14,0,0,1,4.14,4.14v6.21A3.1,3.1,0,0,1,108,86H58.34a3.1,3.1,0,0,1-3.1-3.1V76.66A4.14,4.14,0,0,1,59.38,72.52Z" fill="#acb7d0"/><path id="Shape-2" data-name="Shape" d="M68.69,36.31H108a3.1,3.1,0,0,1,3.1,3.1V54.93H65.59V39.41A3.1,3.1,0,0,1,68.69,36.31Z" fill="#bbdef9"/><polygon id="Shape-3" data-name="Shape" points="78.18 54.93 92.31 36.31 108.86 36.31 94.73 54.93 78.18 54.93" fill="#def0ff"/><polygon id="Shape-4" data-name="Shape" points="69.94 54.93 84.68 36.31 88.17 36.31 73.43 54.93 69.94 54.93" fill="#def0ff"/><polygon id="Shape-5" data-name="Shape" points="66.96 52.86 80.07 36.31 81.1 36.31 68 52.86 66.96 52.86" fill="#def0ff"/><path id="Shape-6" data-name="Shape" d="M66.62,32.17H53.17V28H49V76.66a3.1,3.1,0,0,0,3.1,3.1H66.62a3.1,3.1,0,0,0,3.1-3.1V35.28A3.1,3.1,0,0,0,66.62,32.17Z" fill="#c2cde7"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-2" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="49.03" y="72.52" width="20.69" height="7.24" rx="3" ry="3" fill="#acb7d0"/><path id="Shape-7" data-name="Shape" d="M53.17,32.17h14a2.59,2.59,0,0,1,2.59,2.59h0a2.59,2.59,0,0,1-2.59,2.59h-14Z" fill="#ced9ed"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-3" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="75.93" y="61.14" width="6.21" height="6.21" fill="#ed7899"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-4" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="86.28" y="61.14" width="6.21" height="6.21" fill="#85cbf8"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-5" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="96.62" y="61.14" width="6.21" height="6.21" fill="#85cbf8"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-6" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="75.93" y="71.48" width="6.21" height="6.21" fill="#85cbf8"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-7" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="86.28" y="71.48" width="6.21" height="6.21" fill="#85cbf8"/><rect id="Rectangle-path-8" data-name="Rectangle-path" x="96.62" y="71.48" width="6.21" height="6.21" fill="#72caaf"/><path id="Shape-8" data-name="Shape" d="M81.1,60.1H77a2.07,2.07,0,0,0-2.07,2.07v4.14A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,77,68.38H81.1a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07-2.07V62.17A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,81.1,60.1Zm0,6.21H77V62.17H81.1Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-9" data-name="Shape" d="M91.45,60.1H87.31a2.07,2.07,0,0,0-2.07,2.07v4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07,2.07h4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07-2.07V62.17A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,91.45,60.1Zm0,6.21H87.31V62.17h4.14Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-10" data-name="Shape" d="M91.45,70.45H87.31a2.07,2.07,0,0,0-2.07,2.07v4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07,2.07h4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07-2.07V72.52A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,91.45,70.45Zm0,6.21H87.31V72.52h4.14Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-11" data-name="Shape" d="M101.79,70.45H97.66a2.07,2.07,0,0,0-2.07,2.07v4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07,2.07h4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07-2.07V72.52A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,101.79,70.45Zm0,6.21H97.66V72.52h4.14Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-12" data-name="Shape" d="M101.79,60.1H97.66a2.07,2.07,0,0,0-2.07,2.07v4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07,2.07h4.14a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07-2.07V62.17A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,101.79,60.1Zm0,6.21H97.66V62.17h4.14Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-13" data-name="Shape" d="M81.1,70.45H77a2.07,2.07,0,0,0-2.07,2.07v4.14A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,77,78.72H81.1a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,2.07-2.07V72.52A2.07,2.07,0,0,0,81.1,70.45Zm0,6.21H77V72.52H81.1Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-14" data-name="Shape" d="M78,46.73h1v1H78a1,1,0,1,0,0,2.07h2.07a1,1,0,0,0,1-1v-3.1a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H79V43.55h1a1,1,0,0,0,0-2.07H78a1,1,0,0,0-1,1v3.1a1,1,0,0,0,1,1.11Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-15" data-name="Shape" d="M84.21,46.73h1v1h-1a1,1,0,1,0,0,2.07h2.07a1,1,0,0,0,1-1v-3.1a1,1,0,0,0-1-1h-1V43.55h1a1,1,0,0,0,0-2.07H84.21a1,1,0,0,0-1,1v3.1a1,1,0,0,0,1,1.11Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-16" data-name="Shape" d="M90.41,46.73h1v1h-1a1,1,0,0,0,0,2.07h2.07a1,1,0,0,0,1-1v-3.1a1,1,0,0,0-1-1h-1V43.55h1a1,1,0,1,0,0-2.07H90.41a1,1,0,0,0-1,1v3.1a1,1,0,0,0,1,1.11Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-17" data-name="Shape" d="M100.76,46.73h1v1h-1a1,1,0,1,0,0,2.07h2.07a1,1,0,0,0,1-1v-3.1a1,1,0,0,0-1-1h-1V43.55h1a1,1,0,0,0,0-2.07h-2.07a1,1,0,0,0-1,1v3.1a1,1,0,0,0,1,1.11Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-18" data-name="Shape" d="M109,35.28H70.66a5.17,5.17,0,0,0-5.07-4.14H54.21v-1a3.1,3.1,0,0,0-6.21,0V75.62a5.17,5.17,0,0,0,5.17,5.17h1v3.1a3.1,3.1,0,0,0,3.1,3.1H109a3.1,3.1,0,0,0,3.1-3.1V38.38A3.1,3.1,0,0,0,109,35.28ZM51.1,29.07a1,1,0,0,1,1,1v8.28a1,1,0,0,0,2.07,0V33.21H65.59a3.1,3.1,0,0,1,3.1,3.1V72.52H50.07V30.1A1,1,0,0,1,51.1,29.07Zm-1,46.55v-1H68.69v1a3.1,3.1,0,0,1-3.1,3.1H53.17A3.1,3.1,0,0,1,50.07,75.62Zm59,9.31H57.31a1,1,0,0,1-1-1v-3.1h9.31a5.17,5.17,0,0,0,5.17-5.17V37.34H109a1,1,0,0,1,1,1V53.9H82.14a1,1,0,1,0,0,2.07h27.93V83.9A1,1,0,0,1,109,84.93Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-19" data-name="Shape" d="M95.59,46.66h2.07a1,1,0,0,0,0-2.07H95.59a1,1,0,1,0,0,2.07Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-20" data-name="Shape" d="M54.21,57a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V53.9a1,1,0,1,0-2.07,0V56A1,1,0,0,0,54.21,57Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-21" data-name="Shape" d="M59.38,57a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V53.9a1,1,0,0,0-2.07,0V56A1,1,0,0,0,59.38,57Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-22" data-name="Shape" d="M64.55,57a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V53.9a1,1,0,1,0-2.07,0V56A1,1,0,0,0,64.55,57Z" fill="#2b7db5"/><path id="Shape-23" data-name="Shape" d="M79,54.93a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H73.86a1,1,0,0,0,0,2.07H78A1,1,0,0,0,79,54.93Z" fill="#2b7db5"/></g></g></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark this as answered when you get a chance. (Click checkmark by voting arrows)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the transition is not working is because the rectangle is defined to have `fill="none"`. You can't transition from `none` to a colour.  the keyword "none" means "no fill", so transitioning is equivalent to turning the fill "on". That's why it just appears rather than fading in.

```css
#Rectangle { transition: 1s; }

svg:hover #Rectangle { fill: #DAF0FF; }
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 162 113">
<rect id="Rectangle" x="1" y="1" width="160" height="111" rx="8" ry="8" fill="none" stroke="#2b7db5" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

The solution is to update the rectangle so that it has a fill colour of `transparent` rather than `none`. Transitioning/animating from transparent, to another colour, **is** allowed.

```css
#Rectangle { transition: 1s; }

svg:hover #Rectangle { fill: #DAF0FF; }
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 162 113">
<rect id="Rectangle" x="1" y="1" width="160" height="111" rx="8" ry="8" fill="transparent" stroke="#2b7db5" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```